# SwiftUI: How can I offset a view by a percentage value in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

How can I offset a view by its size percentage? For example, if I want to offset a view by 50% to the right, I would like to write something like:

```
...
Text("some text...").percentageOffset(x: 0.5, y: 0)
...
```

But when I wrap everything in `GeometryReader` then the sizing behavior changes immendiately, it starts taking the whole area given to it.

Comment: You can use `GeometryReader` with a `PreferenceKey` and not affect the sizing: https://www.fivestars.blog/articles/swiftui-share-layout-information/

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.
Usage as in your example.

```
extension View {
    func percentageOffset(x: Double = 0, y: Double = 0) -> some View {
        self
            .modifier(PercentageOffset(x: x, y: y))
    }
}


struct PercentageOffset: ViewModifier  {
    
    let x: Double
    let y: Double
    
    @State private var size: CGSize = .zero
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        
        content
            .background( GeometryReader { geo in Color.clear.onAppear { size = geo.size }})
            .offset(x: size.width * x, y: size.height * y)
    }
}
```

Comment: I have had some problems capturing the geometry state in "onAppear" or "onChange" whenever my views were involved in animations - the 'geo' variable seems to contain the "real time" value of the position/size/etc. It would be so cool to have a way to ask for the view's size directly...